# ALAsset defaultRepresentation issue with iCloud pictures

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, alasset

Using ALAsset, I get a nil answer for a lot of pictures fetched from iCloud in my app when calling the method : defaultRepresentation.
However, when I call "thumbnail" I get the associated small picture.

It mostly happens when the picture has just been added on iCloud from another device. My assumption was that the picture was not fully synchronised yet.

I've read that in this case, I need to subscribe to the ALAsset notifications, thus I could know when the picture is downloaded and update my UI. But some of them are never correctly downloaded, even if I relaunch my app, still nothing.

The strange "workaround" that I found is going in iPhoto and open the pictures in full screen on the device. The issue disappear only for the pictures I opened but remains for the others.

Finally, someone here wrote that it's possible to "force" the download by calling "requestDefaultRepresentation" but this method is not in the Apple documentation so an app using it could be rejected.

My question is : Is there an authorised method to fetch those pictures without asking the user to go in iPhoto ?